# How to determine the URL, URI and Path in C or Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, parsing, url, uri

I need a way in C or Objective-C to separate the URI and the Path, given a full URL.

Example:

Given the URL

```
mms://a11.l412923342423.c658546.g.lm.akamaistream.net/D/13/414392/v0001/reflector:36751
```

Getting the URL is easy, but how can I determine where the URI ends and where the Path starts, in C or Objective-C?

I know that the URI is `a11.l412923342423.c658546.g.lm.akamaistream.net` and that the Path is `D/13/414392/v0001/reflector:36751`, but how to identify that programmatically?

I can't figure that out and any sample code will GREATLY help me. Thank you.

Comment: i dont know what is URI but does it works by searching first "/" in that whole string ?

Comment: I thought about that, but how to identify the other slash, which is not in sequence, for the beginning of the Path?

Comment: Are you coding against Cocoa by any chance? If so, check out `NSURL`.

Comment: Actually against Cocoa Touch. In this case it would work the same way. I'll the the documentation for NSURL. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `//` denotes the start of the URI and a subsequent `/` marks the start of the path:

```
char *uri_start; // Start of URI
int uri_length;  // Length of URI
char *path_start; // Start of Path (until end of string)

uri_start = strstr(url, "//");
if (uri_start == NULL) { 
  uri_start = url;
} else {
  uri_start += 2; // skip "//"
}

path_start = strstr(uri_start, "/");

if (path_start == NULL) { 
  path_start = ""; // Path empty
  uri_length = strlen(uri_start);
} else {
  path_start += 1; // skip "/"
  uri_length = path_start - uri_start - 1;
}
```

**Edit:**
Copying the uri:

```
char uri[300]; // or char *uri = malloc(uri_length + 1);
memcpy(uri, uri_start, uri_length); // Copy the uri
uri[uri_length] = '\0';  // nul-terminate the uri string
```

or (if it is ok, to alter the original string):

```
uri_start[uri_length] = '\0';  // nul-terminates the uri but alters the url
```

Comment: I do appreciate your code very much Klas! I'll try that out and will let you know the results.

Comment: Hey Klas, it worked like a charm! Thanks A LOT! The only thing missing and I couldn't get it right is obtaining the URI alone (a11.l412923342423.c658546.g.lm.akamaistream.net), without the Path attached to it. I tried "subtracting" the Path from the full URL, but it didn't work. Could you please help me out one more?

Comment: Nice! I didn't even run it through a compiler. I've added the code to copy the uri as an addendum to the answer.

Comment: WOW !!! Now it's just working PERFECTLY !!! Maybe in a few years I could have that kind of knowledge !!! Thanks for teaching me, thanks for your time, thanks for your patience, thanks for sharing such a neat piece of code that made my day, and thought me A LOT !!! May the great coders like you be honored, and set a high standard for newbies like me, in all aspects !!! Have a blessed day, my friend !!!

Comment: With the Edit I would give this a +1.. Remember that where as strstr alternates memory... with memcpy the memory areas should not overlap or use memmove

Answer (score 2):

One could look for the third SLASH in the URL, and even test if the first and second are successive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm not well versed in C or Objective-C. Do you have any suggestion for a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of properties on `NSURL` objects that give the various components of the URL.  Have you tried using those?

Comment: I'm the documentation for NSURL now. Thank you!